# Azure B2C Email Validation Template Customization

Tags: email, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am  using Azure B2C to handle user access to my App.  I have an issue with the reset password workflow.

As part of the reset password process a verification email is sent to the registered email address.  However the default template for this is generic and does not look professional or in any way linked to my App.

Is there anyway of customising this template?  I have already customised the B2C html pages but cannot find a template for the email?

Thanks Ash

Comment: Not a feature yet. But you can go vote for it here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334335-fully-customizable-verification-emails

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? If you can share the solution, I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 11):

**Azure AD B2C supports basic customization of emails sent by Azure AD B2C** through Azure AD's [Company Branding feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-company-branding). **Customization of the template is not supported at this time**, though  you can vote for that ask in the Azure AD B2C Feedback forum: [Fully customizable verification emails](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334335-fully-customizable-verification-emails)

An alternative would be for you to avoid using the Reset Password policy at all and implement your own reset password mechanism which:

1. Generates its own codes
2. Sends its own emails
3. Has its own code redemption mechanism
4. [Uses the Graph API to reset the user's password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)

Comment: Hey @Saca... could you please shed some light here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58646052/114029

Comment: The Azure AD Company Branding feature had no effect on the password reset verification code email for me. Anyone know if it should work as described above?

Answer (score 6):

Azure has update it.
Now, it is available here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email

Comment: That's for custom policies only. Not for default userflows.