# Azure AD B2C custom Password reset policy won't validate e-mail with + char\sign

Tags: regex, azure-ad-b2c, email-validation, forgot-password, reset-password

The user could signup and can sign in just fine using Azure AD B2C with an email that contains `+`. However, when clicking "Forgot password" link on the sign-in page and entering their e-mail with a `+` char the following error is displayed:

[image]

I saw 2 related issues on Azure's feedback site:

[allow plus sign in email addresses](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/11351292-allow-plus-sign-in-email-addresses) [ there's a comment by user **Naud van Onna** that matches this question. ]

> I've seen a successful sign-up using a '+' symbol in the email address
>   as well. Unfortunately the password reset functionality is not working
>   using an email address with a '+' symbol.

and

[Support plus-addressing in emails, which is invaluable for testing](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35764951-support-plus-addressing-in-emails-which-is-invalu) [ in this one it's mentioned e-mail `sub-addressing` feature which describes our situation. We use the `+` e-mail addresses to test our application. ]

Is there any place in the custom policies `.xml` files where I can enter a custom regex to validate this e-mail address and allow the `+` sign?

I saw `<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">` in `TrustFrameworkBase.xml` file but I'm not sure where to modify it...

```
<!-- This technical profile forces the user to verify the email address that they provide on the UI. Only after email is verified, the user account is
        read from the directory. -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... after a little bit more research I found the error message "**Please enter a valid e-mail address.**" in the email `ClaimType` inside `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`.

```
<ClaimType Id="email">
<DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
<DataType>string</DataType>
<DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"
    PartnerClaimType="email" />
</DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
<UserHelpText>Email address that can be used to contact you.</UserHelpText>
<UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
<Restriction>
  <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$"
    HelpText="Please enter a valid email address." />
</Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

This regex

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$

is the one that validates the email... we just need to tweek it so that it accepts the `+` sign like this:

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9.+!#$%&'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$

Microsoft doc about [ClaimsSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema).